# How to retrieve the index

Tags: jquery, html

```js
$(function() {
  $(".menu ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).closest("ul").prev().index());
    alert($(this).index());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">C1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="documents">Assessments Not Started</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="messages">Assessments Started</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">C2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="documents">Assessments Not Started</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="messages">Assessments Started</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the PARENT LI index as well as the clicked index from the above.

Example:

```
C2 > Assessments Started (should alert: 1, 1);
C1 > Assessments Not Started (should alert: 0, 0);
```

But it is always displaying 0 as the closest index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parents("li").index());
    alert($(this).index());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">C1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="documents">Assessments Not Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="messages">Assessments Started</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">C2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="documents">Assessments Not Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="messages">Assessments Started</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because you're traversing the DOM and getting the `a` element which is the sibling of the parent `ul`, not the `li` parent. Try this:

```
$(".menu ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).closest('ul').closest('li').index(), $(this).index());
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rqtn3207/)

Answer (score 1):

Select it with the `.parent()` selector.

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu ul").on("click", "li", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).parent().parent().index());
    alert($(this).index());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try please.

```
$(this).closest("ul").parent();
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.